# Request works from browser and not from react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am making this request within my react-native App using axios.

```
const URL = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${address}&key=${GOOGLE_API_KEY}`;
```

I console log the URL right after and get this:

(Note: API Key is made up for this example, I do see the original one)

```
console.log(URL) // https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Carrer de Ali Beii+130,+Barcelona,+España&key=rwzaSyAiBdsd23hrJwWXL873kb5ej2Zjwe3WeT66B_cGS0
```

However, I catch the promise returned by axios and get:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

Furthermore, if I copy paste the console logged URL above ^ into the BROWSER, then I do get the json data. What is going on here?

One more thing: 
If I copy paste the browser transformed URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Carrer%20de%20Ali%20Beii+130,+Barcelona,+Espa%C3%B1a&key=rwzaSyAiBdsd23hrJwWXL873kb5ej2Zjwe3WeT66B_cGS0
```

into my app and make a request, I do get data. Axios is indeed working.
This only leaves me with the conclusion that google is not transforming my request into that browser-like URL???

Comment: what if you put separately host and query string, like baseURL + url + params?

Comment: @MaxDeepfield what difference would it make?

Comment: it would properly handle the values of get params and encode spaces with needed %20

Comment: In the google docs the use this as an example:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY`
My address param is doing exactly that, like so:
`const address = ${street}+${streetNumber},+${city},+${country}` @MaxDeepfield

Comment: what if your street or city has spaces in name? you need to replace all whitespaces, not just connecting ones

Comment: @MaxDeepfield I already went to that extent and replaced all whitespace using `street.replace(/ /g, '%20')` I think it is not replacing the ñ in España and throwing me an error.

Comment: you can easily test for this!

Comment: @MaxDeepfield I am not supposed to be doing all of this.

Comment: @MaxDeepfield doing the request in postman works without doing any formatting. Why should I be doing it?

Comment: really I can not confirm that axios has these problems...

Comment: @MaxDeepfield solved this weird issue by ussing a regEx `const formattedAddress = address.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '%20'); `

Comment: so problem was exactly in url encode... maybe need to write some issues on their github page